# Going on Business Visa (Schengen Visa) and wife will be travelling on Tourist visa (Schengen Visa)

Tags: schengen-visas, tourist-visas, business-travel, denmark

I am planning to travel to Denmark on a business visa (Schengen Visa) for 14 days and I would like to take my wife with me. I have already applied for my business visa and I am looking for an appointment for my wife's visa. Could you please tell me how I can sponsor my wife's visa and what I need to consider if we plan to visit France over the weekend?

Comment: Did you state in your application that your wife would be travelling with you?

Answer (score 5):

In terms of a Schengen tourist visa, "sponsorship" means giving a credible explanation of the source of funds. And in your case, a reason to take the trip now.

- **You** need to explain why you travel (business), who pays for your travel (it is a business expense either for you/your employer or for the company you visit), and why you appear likely to leave afterwards (you have a job and family where you live).
- **Your wife** needs to explain why she travels (taking the opportunity to go with you while you do business), who pays for her travel (your family income, either yours or hers or both), and why she appears likely to leave afterwards (her husband has a job to return to, possibly other ties).

So in a way, having your wife come weakens **your** application. But if you are in a stable financial situation, in a stable country, with a good job to return to, it does not have to destroy your application.

Ask yourself:

- Are you, as a family, able to afford tourism for your wife? You will have to show bank statements with a stable income, reasonable expenditures, and enough money left for a such a luxury.
- Do you, as a family, have plausible reasons to return at the end of your trip? A stable job helps, so does property ownership and more dependents who do *not* join your trip.